# Parse Android Tried to serialize a command referencing a new, unsaved object

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to Parse for Android and when I run the sample project, my logcat constantly outputs the following error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to serialize a command referencing a new, unsaved object.

Does anyone know what is causing this error? Here is my Activity Code:

```
public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {

EditText mTaskInput;
ListView mListView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

    mTaskInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.task_input);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.task_list);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Task.class);       


}

public void createTask(View v) {

      if (mTaskInput.getText().length() > 0){
          Task t = new Task();
          t.setDescription(mTaskInput.getText().toString());
          t.setCompleted(false);
          t.saveInBackground();
          mTaskInput.setText("");
      }
  } 
}
```

And here is my Application class:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();


// Initialize Crash Reporting.
ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

// Add your initialization code here
Parse.initialize(this, APPLICATION_ID, CLIENT_KEY);


ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

// If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}
}
```

Comment: try to register your parseObject in Application class

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, my log cat is spamming the same error

Comment: Can you provide source for Task?